# jqGrid viewGridRow custom button click

Tags: jqgrid

All,

I have created a custom button on `viewGridRow`. See below code snippet. When user clicks on that button I want to show UI dialog and perform some operation and close the window. Within same View window user clicks next row does similar functionality.

I tried adding a id and checked onclick but it doesnt fire. How do I go about adding onclick event on that custom button? Help is appreciated.

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.view, {
        bSubmit: "View details",
        width: 370,
        recreateForm: true,
        beforeShowForm: function (form) {
           var selRowId = $(this).getGridParam('selrow')

            $('<a id="viewBtn" href="#">View Report<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>').addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
                    .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `beforeShowForm` callback to the following for example:

```or-tag-here
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var $self = $(this);
    $('<a id="viewBtn" href="#">View Report<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>')
        .click(function () {
            var selRowId = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
            alert("'View' button on rowid=" + selRowId + " was clicked.");
            return false;
        })
        .addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
        .insertBefore($form.next(".EditTable").find("#cData"));

}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGridWithView.htm) which uses the code displays

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that before but the problem is UI dialog opens behind the View Record not infront of it. User has to submit that UI dialog and close the window and then click next row. If you can give me some ideas that would be great.

Comment: @r500: You are welcome! 99% of all problems with one window (div) behind of another one are based on wrong value of `z-index`. jqGrid uses `$.jgrid.createModal` internally and it uses `z-index` equal to `950`. If you create another dialog and what to display if *over* View dialog the dialog should have z-index higher as 950 (see `zIndex` option of jQuery UI Dialog). Alternatively you can change `z-Index` of View-Dialog in `beforeShowForm`: just add `$form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").css({zIndex: 100});` line which changes `z-index` of View dialog.

Comment: Thank you again. Did not know about Z-index. This time it is overlapping. If I close model window it closes ViewRecord window as well. When I close the window, viewRecord window should still be open. I played with several index sizes but didn't help.

Comment: Tried below code and it perfectly worked for me. $dialog.dialog().parent('.ui-dialog').css('zIndex',9999);

Comment: @r500: OK! I'm glad that your could solve the problem yourself. Typically you could set `zIndex` of dialog directly as the option directly during creating it, but setting `css` will do the same.